# Using native ios views in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

Is there a way to use native ui components except delivered by react native (ListView, Text, etc) in js file?

For example, I have application created by react native and I want to use [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you take a look at [this section of the docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/), under the title "Extensibility", then there's a bit that says "Custom iOS views can be exposed by subclassing RCTViewManager". This should get you started and then you can look at the React Native source code for [examples of view classes that subclass RCTViewManager](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rctviewmanager).